# Como pasar un etiqueta option con todos sus atributos(value,text)?

Tags: javascript, java, web

Quis[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero pasar de izquierda mis opciones, estoy usando un Select con varias option.
Pero necesito que cuando pase un item de izquierda a derecha, en el lado derecho aparezca el texto pero guardare esa lista de la derecha y quiero solo el value.

En pocas palabras quisiera pasar todo el la etiqueta con sus value y su texto pero solo quiero que aparezca el text pero siga teniendo su value.

Comment: para recibir ayuda debes colocar tu parte de tu codigo lo que as intentado hasta ahora!

Comment: Hola, recuerda que es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [ask], te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

primero debes capturar los valores en un array (value, text) del lado izquierdo para luego poder pasarlo al derecho creando un select dinámico a la derecha, aqui un ejm.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001961/how-to-add-drop-down-list-select-programmatically